# Jumping from one slide to another

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

I want to jump from one slide to another in SCORM. How can I do that ? I have a code that is does :

```
//set the value of _root.bookmarkData to 2, this would allow the start the course from beginning.
document.start.setVariable("_root.bookmarkData", "2");
```

But I get an undefined function error for this. Neither have I found the start variable nor the setVariable function.

What should I do to make a jump ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recognize that "start" object that your communicating with.  It may be a Flash to JavaScript interface maybe?

Typically a SCORM content API or 'wrapper' will locate the LMS API, and provide a series of friendly methods like go, stop, start, end, quit and then setting values.

Raw SCORM 1.2 would be locating the LMS API  -

```
var result = API.LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', '2'); // should return 'true'
// or
var bookmark = API.LMSGetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', '2');
```

GL

Comment: But how can you let's say go from SCO number 3 to SCO number 7 (SCOs representing slides of presentation) with some kind of button inside slide number 4. Is it possible maybe with the API?

Comment: Switching between physical SCO's was a SCORM 2004 feature (Sequence and Navigation) *see adl.nav.request.  Bookmarking within a SCO though follows what I mentioned prior.  Thats if you had pages of content within a Single SCO.  Moving through a Lesson structure would depend if the LMS offered you a API call outside of SCORM 1.2 support.

Comment: Is it done through the API and which data model element should I set with `SetValue()`. If you have time please check out [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831980/scorm-jump-between-scos-when-button-in-the-presentation-is-clicked). I will appreciate very much your help. :)