# Captivate multi sco exit button SCORM 2004

Tags: scorm2004, adobe-captivate

I can't find a way to exit a sco in a  multi-sco course.  I've seen there have been problems in Captivate 7 exit buttons and have seen some solutions to get the window to close which are fine with a single sco in it's own window.  But what I need to do is just close the sco and still have the tree menu in the LMS available.  In 1.2, I was able to just call SCORM_CallLMSFinish(), the sco would disappear and  you could make another selection from the tree nav.  Now with 2004, I tried SCORM2004_CallTerminate() which I assumed would be the equivalent but while the connection is ended, the sco is still there.

The sco is not running in it's own window so doing something simple like calling window.close() will close everything including the tree navigation and I don't want it to automatically go to the next sco.

Comment: I've seen that happen with Captivate since in a pop up it would be triggering a window.close() type action.  On a LMS most will tend to let the SCO terminate and then wait for the student to navigate to the next SCO.   Typically, in this situation you'd use a 'adl.nav.request' to 'exit'.  You can also 'continue' to auto-advance to the next SCO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831980/scorm-jump-between-scos-when-button-in-the-presentation-is-clicked

Comment: I've got it pretty close now with by using 'exit'.  Got the sco closing now, saving the bookmark and marking completion when reaching the last slide.  But now after being marked complete, upon opening again, it's marked as incomplete and start from the beginning again.  Is this a function of the LMS or is there something I can do to keep the completed status?

Comment: if the exit type is 'suspend' it should resume.  Its possible the exit type is 'normal' which can start a new attempt when launched a second time.

Comment: Keep in mind too others may tell you to invoke a top.window.close(), but depending on the deployment of your content that can actually have severe side effects including wiping out the LMS window.  There are a awful lot of threads on the subject specially in regards to Captivates [x] button.  Some LMS platforms expose their own exit button too.  But, it is common for SCO's to terminate, then just sit there allowing the student to interact with them wile none of the data is being tracked.